# Quick Access ToolBar resets itself on using Addin in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I have created this **Addin** to make life easier for people to use the Macros.

- This **Addin** creates the Shortcuts using the below code in `Workbook_Open` event.

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim hFile As Long
Dim path As String, fileName As String, ribbonXML As String, user As String

hFile = FreeFile
user = Environ("Username")
path = "C:\Users\" & user & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\"
fileName = "Excel.officeUI"

ribbonXML = "<mso:customUI      xmlns:mso='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui'>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "  <mso:ribbon>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    <mso:qat/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    <mso:tabs>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "      <mso:tab id='reportTab' label='Macros-MB' insertBeforeQ='mso:TabFormat'>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        <mso:group id='reportGroup' label='Macros-MB' autoScale='true'>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='automation1' label='Text_Save' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='FileSave'      onAction='testingmacro'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        </mso:group>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "      </mso:tab>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    </mso:tabs>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "  </mso:ribbon>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "</mso:customUI>"

ribbonXML = Replace(ribbonXML, """", "")

Open path & fileName For Output Access Write As hFile
Print #hFile, ribbonXML
Close hFile

End Sub
```

The problem is that if anyone uses this **Addin**, it resets the Quick Access Toolbar and all of the shortcuts in quick access are gone.

---

**Without using Addin if we open a workbook, Shortcut is there.**

[image: aghsdg]

---

**After Using Addin**

[image]

I am not able to find anything in the code that is causing the Quick Access toolbar to reset itself. Any help appreciated

Comment: Why are you messing about with the user's customisations - that's a **major** faux pas. You should be using the CustomUI part of your add-in for Ribbon customisations.

Comment: @Rory .. Didn't understand what you mean by Custom UI part. :(

Comment: Read this lot: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section2.htm  :)

Comment: @Rory ... Thank you so Much. Using RibbonX worked. And it is a better approach as the code is not visible to user. 